# How can I create checkbox for images using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I was trying to create a checkbox for images where if we have multiple images I can select 3 or 4 images before proceeding ahead. I have seen this kind of thing but I don't know how to create the same using jquery.

For example in this image I would like to give an option that if some one clicks on the image it gets selected. User can select multiple images like this. Is it possible using jquery? or is there  a plugin which can help me to achieve this.

[image: example]

Comment: Googling `jquery image checkbox` gives me some promising results. Do they not work for you?

Comment: that would depend completely on your intentions. Sure, you can have checkboxes, just add them. Without knowing what your page structure is, what needs to be dynamic, and what you intend to do with the information there isn't much of a question here,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be sufficient for your needs. Of course you can edit the script and css to be styled how you like:

```
$('.image-checkbox-container img').live('click', function(){
    if(!$(this).prev('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked')){
        $(this).prev('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true).attr('checked','checked');
        this.style.border = '4px solid #38A';
        this.style.margin =' 0';
    }else{
        $(this).prev('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false).removeAttr('checked');
        this.style.border = '0';
        this.style.margin = '4px';
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.image-checkbox-container input[type="checkbox"]{
    display: none;
}

.image-checkbox-container img{
    border: 0;
    margin: 4px;
}
```

[**Here is a JSFIddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/Ljy8G/)

Comment: the .live() call has been discontinued since javascript 1.9, so to use this in a modern environment you need to replace .live with .on - trivial when you identify the problem but it got me stumped for quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

One of many possible implementations. Here I assume you generate a list of images and corresponding checkboxes beforehand (not with javascript).

HTML (snipped):

```
<div id="selectable_images">
   <img src="/image1.jpg" rel="ch_image_1"/>
   <input style="display:none" type="checkbox" id="ch_image_1" value="image1.jpg"/>

   <img src="/image2.jpg" rel="ch_image_2"/>
   <input style="display:none" type="checkbox" id="ch_image_2" value="image2.jpg"/>

   <img src="/image3.jpg" rel="ch_image_3"/>
   <input style="display:none" type="checkbox" id="ch_image_3" value="image3.jpg"/>
</div>
```

JS (jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectable_images img").click(function() {
       var $this = $(this);
       if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
           $("#"+this.rel).attr('checked', false);
           $this.removeClass('selected');
       } else {
           $("#"+this.rel).attr('checked', true);
           $this.addClass('selected');
       }
    })
}
```

By clicking on the images corresponding checkboxes would be toggled. The selected image would get "selected" class.